# Algebraic curves that enclose and exclude given points in the plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

> ***Q1***. Given two finite sets $R,G$ of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$,
>   $|R|=r$ red points and $|G|=g$ green points,
>   is it always possible to find a simple closed algebraic curve $C(x,y)=0$
>   that encloses the green points and excludes the red points?
>   (*See Update below.*)

Let's say the green points can be on the boundary of $C$.

For example,

---

[image: PearCurve]

---

the degree-$8$ "pear" curve
$$
\left(x^2+y^2\right) \left(x^6+4 x^5+3 x^4 y^2+6 x^4+8 x^3 y^2+6
   x^3+3 x^2 y^4+8 x^2 y^2+5 x^2+4 x y^4-2 x y^2+2 x+y^6+2 y^4-3
   y^2+1\right)-(1.2)^2 = 0
$$
would be a solution for the illustrated instance.

> ***Q2***. If this is always possible, can the degree of $C$ be
>   bounded in terms of $r$ and $g$?
>
> ***Q3***. Is there a way to find a solution $C$ of minimal degree?

---

***Update***.
Alex Degtyarev and Mariano Suárez-Alvarez both answer ***Q1***:
*Yes*, this is always possible. Alex has a bound for ***Q2***. 
The minimal degree (***Q3***) seems out of reach at the moment.

Comment: For Q1, cannot we just take _a_ curve and use Weierstrass approximation? For Q2, I would suggest to pick a generic projection and take an interpolation polynomial (probably, first moving the points up/down by an $\epsilon$). Then, make it even degree (adding an extra point, if necessary), add a horizontal line, and perturb. This gives _some_ bound on the degree, but probably not the best one.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev: Thanks for the Weierstrass approximation reference!

Comment: Sorry, I guess my recipe for Q2 does not give a connected curve. Here is a bound of order $2g+\mathrm{const}$: take a graph $y=p(x)$ of even degree $d\approx g$ passing through $G$ but not $R$ and consider $(y-p(x))^2=\epsilon(C-y^2)$ for $C\gg0$ and $0<\epsilon\ll1$.

Comment: Draw a curve which does what you want and approximate it by an algebraic one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104609/algebraic-curve-approximation

Comment: For further reference: red and green points are isomorphic to us colorblind people...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: My apologies!